# I have 2 buttons inside an iframe inserting text to parents textarea, but replacing each other

Tags: html, button, iframe, parent

So I don't want the buttons to replace each others text, but insert the first pressed button text to the first line, and second to second line, and so on, when I have more buttons. So I think there is very simple answer to this, but I can't find the exact answer anywhere.

Here's the code of my problematic situation:

front page:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function hello(string)
  {
     var name=string
     document.getElementById('myAnchor').value=name;
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form><textarea id="myAnchor"></textarea></form>
<iframe src="buttonitesti_1.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

`buttonitesti_1.html` page inside the iframe:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
 content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
  <input value="knaapi" onclick="parent.hello('ekaknaapi')" type="button">
  <input value="knaapi2" onclick="parent.hello('tokaknaapi')" type="button">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The buttons aren't replacing one another when I run the code. Maybe I'm not sure what you're asking, could you please elaborate a little further?

Answer (score 0):

Your `hello` function is written to set the value of the textarea.  What you need to do instead is get the current value of the textarea, if the value isn't blank add a newline character, and append the new text:

```
function hello(string)
{
    // get the current text, add a newline if not blank, and append new
    // text
    var anchorText = document.getElementById('myAnchor').value;
    if(anchorText !== "") anchorText += '\n';
    anchorText += string;
    document.getElementById('myAnchor').value=anchorText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IvIbOxA/1/edit)***

```
<!doctype html>  
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    <textarea id="myAnchor"></textarea>
</form>
<iframe src="buttonitesti_1.html"></iframe>

<script>
    function hello( obj ){
        document.getElementById('myAnchor').value = obj.data;
    }
    addEventListener("message", hello, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

buttonitesti_1.html

```
<!doctype html>  
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<input onclick="parent.postMessage('ekaknaapi', '*')" type="button">
<input onclick="parent.postMessage('tokaknaapi', '*')" type="button">

</body>
</html>
```

***[more info about window.postMessage at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage)***